# How can I create an array depending on if variables are set in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have 5 variables:

```
var item_id
var status
var next_contact
var email
var phone_number
var comment
```

These are sent in a POST request to my server in an array:

```
d = {'item_id': item_id, 'status': status, 'next_contact': next_contact, 'email': email, 'phone_number': phone_number, 'comment': comment}
```

Before making the request I want to check which variables are empty and if they are empty I want to remove them from the POST request.

How could one achieve that in a minimal and clean way?

I was thinking of doing it like this for each variable:

```
d = [];

if(email != '') {
   d.push('email': email);
}
```

Is that a good idea?

Thanks!

Comment: @lsmailp, for clarification, have you already created `d`?

Comment: yes, I have. But if there is a way of doing it with out creating it perhaps that is cleaner?

Comment: Create an object initially instead of all the variables, then just access the object properties like so: `obj.item_id = 'thing'`, then it's easier to loop over and serialise when you want to post it off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `d` is an *object*, you can just loop over it removing the properties where the value is null or empty:

```
for (var k in d) {
  if (d[k] === null || d[k] === '') delete d[k];
}
```

Comment: I think he's talking about how to create `d` based on the variables, isn't he?

Answer (score 0):

another approach would be to make an `item` object, and assign your variables as properties. You could then use a function to iterate over this object, and return values as another object that you can pass to your POST request.

```
// this would make a nice "class" or model
var item = {};

item.id = 1;
item.status = "complete";
item.email = undefined;
item.null = null;
item.empty = '';
// etc...

// get non falsey values
function getValues(item) {
  var values = {};
  for (var prop in item) {
    if (item.hasOwnProperty(prop) && item[prop]) {
      values[prop] = item[prop];
    }
  }
  return values;
}

d = getValues(item);
console.log(d); // {id: 1, status: "complete"}
```